# Name of film where end scene has ringed planet rising over ocean?

Tags: story-identification, movie

I have been trying to find out what this film was called - I saw it years ago. It was about a man who was the last man on earth, but then found another 2 people. I can't remember the rest until the end where he wakes up on a beach then a huge ringed planet rises above the ocean. I think it was an Australian film but cannot say for certain. If anyone can name it I would be very grateful.

EDIT: I think it was sometime in the 1980s

Comment: @kylejones - It is not accepted practice to post-edit solved story-identification question with a property tag.

Comment: @Valorum What is the point of tags other than to help people find posts?  Since we know that the quiet-earth tag is appropriate, why not add it?  I only added the tags to questions with accepted answers.

Comment: @KyleJones - Well, for starters it makes the OP look foolish.

Comment: @KyleJones - This was discussed (inconclusively) quite a few years ago. I recall that echoing policy on other stacks, we don't do it http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/671/should-we-tag-solved-story-identification-questions-with-the-name-of-the-autho. If you want to re-raise the issue to try to get a greater consensus (one way or another), I'd be supportive of asking the question again.

Comment: It would also mean an extreme amount of editing to make all ID questions with accepted answers fit this as they do not do so at this point. If you already know the book/film, why do you care that someone's asked an ID question about it? What benefit is an ID question to someone interested in this story?

Comment: @Valorum.  Too much bureaucracy for a few tag edits.

Comment: @Catija I'm not calling for any mass edit.  I added these tags because I was searching for "Quiet Earth" related questions and noticed that the tag didn't locate a question/answer that I distinctly remembered.  So I fixed it.  That's how the site improves, by people doing what they can with the time they have available.  As for why I would search for such a question, one question mentioned a detail that I couldn't quite remember.  This is more efficient than finding a copy of the film and rewatching it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[image: Final shot]

This sounds like the film [The Quiet Earth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Quiet_Earth_%28film%29).

Comment: Definitely.  Wish I'd never seen this awful film, and of course I can't forget it.

Comment: Yes that is the film. Thanks.

Comment: @KyleJones I must admit to having a soft spot for it despite the dire acting. It also has one of the most striking images of any sci-fi film with that end scene (in my opinion). It is not a great film overall, but that last image has stayed in my mind for many years since seeing it.

Comment: @bazz That image was the reason I rented the film years ago.  I figured there had to be an interesting story to lead to _that_ image.  I'm still hoping someone will write it. :(